# Print known attributes from XML in PHP with SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xpath, xml-attribute

Given the following XML:

```
<RegItems>
   <RegItem Name="Test Regger" Email="me@here.com" OrgName="XXX">
      <Establishment Est_Name="Test Org 1" Est_Addr="Test Org 1, 1 Acacia Ave, London, W12 8QT, UK" Est_ContactName="Test One" Est_ContactNum ="321321321" Est_EmailAdd = "test@here.com" />
      <Screens>
         <Timestamp time="Sun, 10 Feb 2019 00:05:24 GMT"/>
         <Screen PDate="2019-01-19" EDate="2019-12-13" SModel="Xi75" Sno="750001"  PCModSno="PC106-0001" PORef="444"/>
      </Screens>
      <UID hash ="dea31a69b70be709fb079bf7d50b1821"/>
   </RegItem>
</RegItems>
```

I have the following PHP code to extract all the data, but I get blanks returned for each attribute in the formatted message.

```
   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($regXML);
   var_dump ($xml);
   $regName = $xml->xpath("/RegItem")['Name'];
   $regEmail = $xml->xpath("/RegItem")['Email'];
   $regOrgName = $xml->xpath("/RegItem")['OrgName'];
   $regEstOrgName = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Establishment")['Est_Name'];
   $regEstOrgAddr = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Establishment")['Est_Addr'];
   $regEstOrgContact = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Establishment")['Est_ContactName'];
   $regEstOrgTel = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Establishment")['Est_ContactNum'];
   $regEstOrgEmail = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Establishment")['Est_EmailAdd'];
   $regTimeStamp = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Timestamp")['time'];

   $mesg = <<<EOF


=====================================================
   Origin XML: $regXML
=====================================================   
   Registered By Details:

   Name:         $regName
   Email:        $regEmail
   Organistion:  $regOrgName

   Registered Organisation:

   Name:           $regOrgName
   Address:        $regEstOrgAddr
   Contact Name:   $regEstOrgContact
   Contact Tel:    $regEstOrgTel
   Contact Email:  $regEstOrgEmail
   Time:           $regTimeStamp
=====================================================   
   Screens:

EOF;

   $screens = $xml->xpath("/RegItem/Screens/Screen");
   foreach($screens as $screen) 
   { 
      $screenWarrStartDate = $screen['PDate'];
      $screenWarrEndDate = $screen['EDate'];
      $screenModel = $screen['SModel'];
      $screenSerial = $screen['Sno'];
      $screenPCSerial = $screen['PCModSno'];
      $screenPORef = $screen['PORef'];

      $mesg .= <<< EOF

         Screen Model:      $screenModel
         Screen Serial No:  $screenSerial
         PC Mod Serial No:  $screenPCSerial
         PO Ref:            $screenPORef
         Warranty Start:    $screenWarrStartDate
         Warranty End:      $screenWarrEndDate

EOF;

   } 

   $mesg .= "
   =====================================================
";

   return ( $mesg );
```

E.g. instead of

```
   Name:         Test Regger
   Email:        me@here.com
   Organistion:  XXX
```

I get:

```
   Name:         
   Email:        
   Organistion:
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of issues with your code. Firstly, `xpath` returns an array of elements, so to access an individual value you need to give an array index. In your case, since there is only one `RegItem`, you can just use `[0]`. Secondly, `RegItem` is not the top-level element in the XML, so the XPath `/RegItem` will not match anything. You need to change it to either `/RegItems/RegItem` or `//RegItem` (the latter finds a `RegItem` at any depth). So for example, to get the `Name` attribute of `RegItem` you would need this:

```
$regName = $xml->xpath("//RegItem")[0]['Name'];
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. The other answer beat you to it but I tried using your shorter hand notation too and that worked as well, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues:

1. Your Xpath expression is incorrect. You have `/RegItem`. The first single / means start from the root of the document. The root is the `RegItems` element. You can either change it to `/RegItems/RegItem` or to `//RegItem` (double-slash means find that element anywhere in the XML tree.
2. The Xpath query returns a list of items. If you want to access the first element you can use `->item(0)`, e.g. `$xml->xpath("/RegItems/RegItem")->item(0)`
3. To access the property of an element, use `getAttribute()`, e.g. `$xml->xpath("/RegItems/RegItem")->item(0)->getAttribute('Name')`